# make the search textbox in dataTables toUpperCase

Tags: javascript, datatables

I want to make the string of Search Textbox of dataTables to Upper Case, not only the css, but also the string.

Can I do that ?

*note : I want the upper case as the default, even when the capslock not active

Comment: Call `.toUpperCase()` on the value on `keyup` and `change`.

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen This is 2016, we have `input`.

Comment: Thank you.. I  think I've wrong place to put the .toUpperCase @EmilS.Jørgensen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To all CSS answers, the question states that the actual property must be uppercase, not just appear that way through styling.

Here is a quick vanilla JavaScript example that should run on any modern browser:

```js
//Function to change case
function upperCaseValue(element) {
  //Test that passed element has a "value" field
  if( typeof element.value !== void 0) {
    //Overwrite value
    element.value = element.value.toUpperCase();
  }
}

//Fetch elements to watch
var search = document.getElementById("search");
var output = document.getElementById("output");
//Bind events
search.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
  //Change case
  upperCaseValue(search);
  //Use input
  output.innerHTML = search.value;
});
search.addEventListener("change", function(){
  //Change case
  upperCaseValue(search);
  //Use input
  output.innerHTML = search.value;
});
```

```css
#search {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<input name="search" id="search" />
<p id="output"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this style to your input element.

HTML

```
<input name="search" id="search" />
```

CSS

```
#search {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just add this styling

```
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter input
{
 text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

**fiddle link** [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/UvjnT/958/)